# How to change the redirect_uri in moziila_django_oidc?

Tags: django, keycloak, openid-connect

I want to integrate Keycloak into a Django project and I am using mozilla_django_oidc to do so.

The problem I have is that when I send a request to the authorization endpoint of keycloak the `redirect_uri` is being set as: `redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdjango%3A8000%2Foidc%2Fcallback%2F`, but instead of `django` there should be the IP of my application. I don't know why it uses django as the domain name.

My configuration in the `settings.py` looks like this:

```
OIDC_RP_CLIENT_ID = os.environ['OIDC_RP_CLIENT_ID']
OIDC_RP_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ['OIDC_RP_CLIENT_SECRET']

OIDC_OP_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = 'http://172.20.159.83:8080/auth/realms/Test/protocol/openid-connect/auth'
OIDC_OP_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = 'http://172.20.159.83:8080/auth/realms/Test/protocol/openid-connect/token'
OIDC_OP_USER_ENDPOINT = 'http://172.20.159.83:8080/auth/realms/Test/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo'
OIDC_OP_JWKS_ENDPOINT = 'http://172.20.159.83:8080/auth/realms/Test/protocol/openid-connect/certs'


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://172.20.159.83/test'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://172.20.159.83/'
```

And in the `urls.py` it is:

```
path('oidc/', include('mozilla_django_oidc.urls')),
```

The request to the authorization endpoint with all parameters:

```
http://172.20.159.83:8080/auth/realms/Test/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&scope=openid+email&client_id=MyApplication&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdjango%3A8000%2Foidc%2Fcallback%2F&state=3YxLAg8kX1bC1yTDMqKh8L05bIP5z9cB&nonce=jZ6KEZhk9tWOwdXRSqTUoF8lzg7aLU70
```

So, as the title says, how can I change the `django` part of the `redirect` uri to point to the IP of my application? How is this parameter being set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, currently, mozilla_django_oidc does not use the hostname, but the value of the Host header; and redirects to IPs as well -- since the port in your redirect URI (`http://django:8000/oidc/callback/`) differs from 8080 too, I'd guess you are using a reverse proxy which does not pass the Host header to the backend server.

For nginx, `proxy_set_header Host $host ;` might help, other reverse proxies might have similar settings.

Comment: You are indeed right, I did solve this problem with `proxy_set_header Host $host;` but only a few days later and kinda forgot about this post. Thanks for pointing this out for anyone else who might find this.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking through the Source code of `mozilla_django_oidc` and it appears that this parameter can not be set manually. Rather it will always use the hostname sending the request (which does happen to django in my case).

Here the code snipped responsible for anyone wondering:

```py
reverse_url = self.get_settings('OIDC_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_URL',
                                        'oidc_authentication_callback')
token_payload = {
            'client_id': self.OIDC_RP_CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret': self.OIDC_RP_CLIENT_SECRET,
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': code,
            'redirect_uri': absolutify(
                self.request,
                reverse(reverse_url)
            ),
        }
```

and absolutify is a function defined as:

```py
def absolutify(request, path):
    """Return the absolute URL of a path."""
    return request.build_absolute_uri(path)
```

Comment: Would this be any different if I am hosting and using keycloak on localhost?

Comment: In which file this code snippet will take place to resolve the issue? @Marius Kimmina